# Invalid tag nesting configuration in ColdFusion 10?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do I get around this ColdFusion error?
I'm following [this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/5/31/ColdFusion-Sample--Upload-and-Parse-an-Excel-File#c2B83CEA5-B456-E9C5-A8ED68A063F6FB90) ColdFusion tutorial. When I tried to implement the code in ColdFusion 10 I got the following error:

> Invalid tag nesting configuration.  A query driven queryloop tag is
>   nested inside a queryloop tag that also has a query attribute. This is
>   not allowed. Nesting these tags implies that you want to use grouped
>   processing. However, only the top-level tag can specify the query that
>   drives the processing.
>
> The error occurred in line 76
>
> `74 : </cfloop>`
>
> `75 : </tr>`
>
> `76 : <cfoutput query="data" startRow="2">`
>
> `77 : <tr>`
>
> `78 : <cfloop index="c" list="#colList`

Here is the code:

```
<cfset showForm = true>
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "xlsfile") and len(form.xlsfile)>

    <!--- Destination outside of web root --->
    <cfset dest = getTempDirectory()>

    <cffile action="upload" destination="#dest#" filefield="xlsfile" result="upload" nameconflict="makeunique">

    <cfif upload.fileWasSaved>
        <cfset theFile = upload.serverDirectory & "/" & upload.serverFile>
        <cfif isSpreadsheetFile(theFile)>
            <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFile#" query="data" headerrow="1">
            <cffile action="delete" file="#theFile#">
            <cfset showForm = false>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset errors = "The file was not an Excel file.">
            <cffile action="delete" file="#theFile#">
        </cfif>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset errors = "The file was not properly uploaded.">   
    </cfif>
</cfif>
<cfif showForm>
    <cfif structKeyExists(variables, "errors")>
        <cfoutput>
            <p>
                <b>Error: #variables.errors#</b>
            </p>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfif>

    <form action="test.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="xlsfile" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload XLS File">
    </form>
<cfelse>
    <style>
        .ssTable {
            width: 100%; 
             border-style:solid;
             border-width:thin;
        }
        .ssHeader { background-color: #ffff00; }
        .ssTable td, .ssTable th { 
            padding: 10px; 
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:thin;
        }
    </style>
    <p>
    Here is the data in your Excel sheet (assuming first row as headers):
    </p>

    <cfset metadata = getMetadata(data)>
    <cfset colList = "">
    <cfloop index="col" array="#metadata#">
        <cfset colList = listAppend(colList, col.name)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfif data.recordCount is 1>
        <p>
        This spreadsheet appeared to have no data.
        </p>
    <cfelse>
        <table class="ssTable">
            <tr class="ssHeader">
                <cfloop index="c" list="#colList#">
                    <cfoutput><th>#c#</th></cfoutput>
                </cfloop>
            </tr>
            <cfoutput query="data" startRow="2">
                <tr>
                <cfloop index="c" list="#colList#">
                    <td>#data[c][currentRow]#</td>
                </cfloop>
                </tr>                    
            </cfoutput>
        </table>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Is that all supposed to be one block of code and you've not paid attn to the formatting being bung, or are you trying to impart some sort of information by the way you've formatted it?

Comment: Is that really the code generating the error? I think not, because the above does not *contain* any nested query loops..

Comment: Whatever code you are running to get that error, it is neither the code you posted above, nor the code on Ray's blog. Post the ACTUAL code you are running. There is no nested output in that code.

Comment: It is supposed to be one block of code. He just updated after responding to my issue with the code on his website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop query="data" startRow="2">
        <tr>
        <cfloop index="c" list="#colList#">
            <td>#data[c][currentRow]#</td>
        </cfloop>
        </tr>                    
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```